# Click on button to pop-up new window with passing URL in .net c# web application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I'm new in .net C#, just a question here. how can I click a button then it will pop-up a new window to display a page?

example:
If I have a page test.aspx, how can I code in .net c# web application so that it will pop-up a new window to display this page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing intrinsic with ASP.NET or C# that does this. You're still outputting Html, so the methods of doing such a thing in JavaScript or `target="_blank"` in a link will still work.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `window.open("test.aspx");` in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a nice looking solution, you can use a JavaScript implemenation called ColorBox
http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/

You would render that second page as an Iframe inside a dialog / popup.
See this example page http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/core/example5/index.html: Other Content Types -> Outside Webpage (Iframe)

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET [HyperLink Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.target.aspx) is another way. You have access to it's properties on code-behind if you need to manipulate the Url programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

if you use  Open a new Window  then it will opens in new window.